# Array initializer is not allowed here

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on Android project and I am getting an error which I cannot understand:

> Array initializer is not allowed here

I tried to simplify my code and it comes down to this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    int pos = {0, 1, 2};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        pos = {2, 1, 0};
    }
}
```

What is going on here?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You should use

```
pos = new int[]{1,2,3};
```

You can only use the abbreviated syntax `int[] pos = {0,1,2};` at variable initialization time.

```
private int[] values1 = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
private int[] values2 = {1,2,3,4}; // short form is allowed only at variable initialization
```

Answer (score 11):

Your initialization statement is wrong: **you must add square brackets** to declare an array (and here you can omit the `new` keyword because you're declaring and initializing the variable at the same time):

```
int[] pos = { 0, 1, 2 };
```

**In the `onCreate` method, you can't omit the `new` keyword** because the variable was already declared, so you have to write:

```
pos = new int[] { 2, 1, 0 };
```

You can read the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and the [Java Language Specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) for more details.

Answer (score 7):

use the following syntax to declare/initialize and empty array, and then populated it with data:

```
String[] menuArray = {};
menuArray = new String[]{"new item","item 2"};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a compile-time error Illegal Initializer for int.
You could solve this problem by adding square braces after your variable's data type like this:

```
int[] pos = {0, 1, 2};
```